# Is it safe to bypass laravel/eloquent to change database data?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have to delete user data in a database used by a laravel/eloquent application. It can be done with some SQL queries.

Problem: I have no clue of laravel/eloquent. That's where I need your help.
Is it safe to bypass laravel/eloquent and just change/delete data in the database using SQL queries (manually or with a script)?

Comment: It totally depends on how safe your database is setup. If the correct `ON DELETE` properties are set, you mostly be fine. If you are not sure, backup the database, run your queries, test if the application is still working correct and if not, import the backup. If you don't care about the data in the database and you have access to your application you can use Laravels `php artisan migrate:fresh` cli command to run the database migration, remove all the data you will have a clean db.

Comment: The documentation is always a good place to read on stuff you are unsure of. Laravel has an exceptionally good and easy to read documentation.

Specifically for your case, Laravel has a built in Query Builder, where you are able to write raw SQL queries, if you don't want to rely on Eloquent.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: @OskarMikael unforunately I have no clue of laravel/eloquent to the point where it would take some time just to learn where to add and how to execute such raw expressions. That's why I asked for the risk of bypassing the whole framework.

Comment: Sure you can use regular SQL expressions, but it will sort of undermine the reason to use Laravel. I don't know in what scenario you are in so I can't speak much of it.

Comment: @OskarMikael I am in the unpleasant situation no knowledge of the implementation is left in the company, just of the database structure (me). Fixing the knowledge/employee situation takes time where data adjustment must be done within thight timeframe (european GDPR...). Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't really need to learn anything,  using laravel DB is like making sql statements, ex : `DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', 1)->delete();`. And even with eloquent its pretty simple : `User::where('id', '=', 1)->delete()`. If your project use soft delete, you will need to use `->forceDelete()` instead of `->delete()` if you want to completely remove data

Comment: If it is GDPR, would that not insinuate this is a one-off? and you can just run the query in the DB?

Comment: @BenDavison it might happen whenever users insist on data change not implemented in the application. I would love to just run the query in the DB but do not know if this breaks something in the application (cache, ...). Therefore I asked if bypassing laravel/eloquent is safe (absolute beginner question).

Comment: @Lk77 thanks for the details provided. My problem is not only what to code, but also where to place it and how to call the "webpage" for executing it. As said, unfortunatly I have not clue of the framework making a bypass to be the most (time) efficient way for me.

Comment: Well it's fine to do it with a sql query directly, if it's a manual action, you just need to be sure to delete everything, like data related to user in other tables, and also backups of the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the assurance provided in the comments of my original question I deleted the data using some SQL statements, executed by the phpMyAdmin SQL feature.

Everything worked as expected.

Of course I studied the data model, backuped everything, and run tests on a copy of the database before performing the change on the production system.